# How do I reset my password? Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I have Ubuntu 12.04, and I set my account to "log in without a password". Now I'm not able to set a password, nor am I able to perform administrative actions. May I please have some help?

Also, does anybody know where I can suggest to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you go in the password and keys application (in the dashboard, research in the installed applications).
then in password, right click, change password.

another way to do it, go in your system settings (icon top right), then in User accounts you will be able to manage it.

Comment: That won't typically help, if someone doesn't currently know their password. (There are some situations where resetting it helps even though it doesn't work for most other purposes, so this answer is potentially valuable, but the password will probably have to be [reset](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password).)

Comment: yes you're right : for a reset purpose, the link given above is far more useful. but i am not sure you have to reset in her case (log without password) ?